# How to apply jQuery auto-complete in a Form-Set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formsets

I'm stick at my thinking on how to apply a JS code to a form-set.

I've this HTML:

```
<input id="id_form-0-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-0-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input">
```

And I use this JS/jQuery code to auto-complete the #id_form-0-city_input input.

```
    // Autocomplete stuff  
    $( "#id_form-0-city_input" ).autocomplete({  // mudar!!!!
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/internalapi/cidades/",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    country: $('#id_country').find(":selected").val(),
                    term: request.term.toLowerCase()
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response($.map(data, function( item ) {    
                        return {
                            label: item.name + " (" + item.zone + ", " + item.municipality + ")",
                            value: item.name,
                               id: item.id
                        }     
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var selectedObj = ui.item;
            // Popular o campo id_city
            $( "#id_form-0-city" ).val(selectedObj.id);
        },
        search: function(event, ui) { 
            $("#id_form-0-city_input").addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" ); // mudar!!!!!
        },
        open: function() {
            $("#id_form-0-city_input").removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" ); // mudar!!!!
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
```

The code above works great, but now I need to use this auto-complete code for this case:

```
<input id="id_form-0-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-0-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input">

<input id="id_form-1-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-1-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input">

<input id="id_form-2-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-2-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input">

<input id="id_form-3-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-3-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input">

<input id="id_form-4-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-4-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input">

...
...
```

The number of sets could be minimum 1 and maximum 10.

Can you give me some ideas to refactor the JS/jQuery code to work with formsets? A for loop is what I need to use?

Comment: Why not just apply a class to each of the inputs, then use your code but change `$( "#id_form-0-city_input" ).autocomplete()` to `$( ".class" ).autocomplete()`? Also instances of `$("#id_form-0-city_input")` change it to `$(this).prev()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a rel element to your inputs if you don't want to use class, like:

```
<input id="id_form-0-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-0-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input" rel="autocomplete">

<input id="id_form-1-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-1-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input" rel="autocomplete">

<input id="id_form-2-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-2-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input" rel="autocomplete">

<input id="id_form-3-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-3-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input" rel="autocomplete">

<input id="id_form-4-city" name="id_form-0-city" type="hidden">
<input id="id_form-4-city_input" name="id_form-0-city_input" rel="autocomplete">
```

And then just add the autocomplete logic inside this

```
$("input[rel='autocomplete']").autocomplete({  // mudar!!!!
...
```

Comment: Why not just use a class then?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop...

```
var inputLength = $('input:not(input[type="hidden"])').length; //find non-hidden inputs

for(var a = 0; a<inputLength; a++){
   // Autocomplete stuff  
    $( "#id_form-" + a + "-city_input" ).autocomplete({  // mudar!!!!
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/internalapi/cidades/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                country: $('#id_country').find(":selected").val(),
                term: request.term.toLowerCase()
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response($.map(data, function( item ) {    
                    return {
                        label: item.name + " (" + item.zone + ", " + item.municipality + ")",
                        value: item.name,
                           id: item.id
                    }     
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var selectedObj = ui.item;
        // Popular o campo id_city
        $( "#id_form-" + a + "-city" ).val(selectedObj.id);
    },
    search: function(event, ui) { 
        $("#id_form-" + a + "-city_input").addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" ); // mudar!!!!!
    },
    open: function() {
        $("#id_form-" + a + "-city_input").removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" ); // mudar!!!!
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
    }); 
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/NcTpj/10/